# Tools to convert XML to HTML using XSLT

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xml, xslt-tools

I'm beginning to work on a project which has some extensive XML XSLT processing to render output HTML.

Some changes need to be made to the XSLT and I need some tool that can help me modify it without having to run the solution every time. Something that can help me visualize the changes I'm making to the rendered HTML.

I've found [StylusStudio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/) but I preferably would want a freeware that I could use

Answer (score 3):

It's not freeware, but [Altova XMLSPY](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) is pretty powerful XML IDE. It offers an XSLT debugger where you can step through your conversion, as well as generate output(HTML in your case) from a sample XML document with the XSLT document you are working on.